# Accessing gRPC request object in custom interceptor/middleware

Tags: go, middleware, interceptor, grpc

gRPC's Go library provides interfaces for creating your own custom interceptors (i.e. middleware functions), and I'm attempting to write two logging interceptors. The first is a Unary Server Interceptor where I'm easily able to log the request parameters using the object passed into the interceptor function.

```
func loggingUnary(context context.Context, req interface{}, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (interface{}, error) {
    start := time.Now()
    resp, err := handler(context, req)

    printLogMessage(err, info.FullMethod, context, time.Since(start), req)

    return resp, err
}
```

How can I do the same with the Stream Server Interceptor which doesn't conveniently pass the request object as a parameter? Is there another way to access the request?

```
func loggingStream(srv interface{}, stream grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
    start := time.Now()
    err := handler(srv, stream)

    printLogMessage(err, info.FullMethod, stream.Context(), time.Since(start), "")

    return err
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit old now, but the easiest way to extend your interception into the stream is to create a **grpc.ServerStream** wrapper, then wrap the real ServerStream in your interceptor. In that way, your intercepting code can handle the received and sent messages in the stream.

```
// A wrapper for the real grpc.ServerStream
type LoggingServerStream struct {
    inner           grpc.ServerStream
}

func (l LoggingServerStream) SetHeader(m metadata.MD) error {
    return l.SetHeader(m)
}

func (l LoggingServerStream) SendHeader(m metadata.MD) error {
    return l.SendHeader(m)
}

func (l LoggingServerStream) SetTrailer(m metadata.MD) {
    l.SetTrailer(m)
}

func (l LoggingServerStream) Context() context.Context {
    return l.Context()
}

func (l LoggingServerStream) SendMsg(m interface{}) error {
    fmt.Printf("Sending Message: type=%s\n", reflect.TypeOf(m).String())
    return l.SendMsg(m)
}

func (l LoggingServerStream) RecvMsg(m interface{}) error {
    fmt.Printf("Receiving Message: type=%s\n", reflect.TypeOf(m).String())
    return l.RecvMsg(m)
}
```

The interceptor:

```
func LoggingStreamInterceptor() grpc.StreamServerInterceptor {
    return func(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
        return handler(srv, LoggingServerStream{inner:ss})
    }
}
```

Any state you need to keep and go in your wrapper.

Comment: The above code doesn't answer the question of how to get the actual request. This code intercepts the server stream rather than the request.

Comment: I confirm your solution work, but you make a little error it' not 'return l.RecvMsg(m)' but 'l.inner.RecvMsg(m)'. The message in RecvMsg is effectively the request itself.

Answer (score 1):

The stream handler can be called multiple times during the lifetime of the request that created the stream, that's why the request is not part of the arguments to the handler (and to any interceptor, either). You could place the request (or better, a copy of the data that you want logged and not a reference to the request itself) in the stream context (assuming you are in control of the code that creates the ServerStream object). I would rather log the request parameters once, when the stream is created and not on every call to the handler (so each request is logged once only).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If by "in control of the code that creates the ServerStream object", you mean control over the clients that make RPC calls, then no, I don't have control. I am, however, in control of all the server-side code. How else could I access the request?

Comment: No, I meant the part of the GO program that creates the ServerStream (the thing that listens for those requests that you want to see and log). That code should be part of your executable (though not necessarily something you wrote - it may be in a package someone else developed, I can't know that).

Comment: @LeoK Unless you're writing your own GRPC server rather than using the built-in one, this is impossible.